# Cassandra upgrade to 6.0 version from 3.2.4

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a production environment, where we have a 4 node Cassandra cluster and this environment has a data with TTL of 730 days and the data has accumulated to a very large amount (14 TB of data). We know this is not ideal. We have a spring based java application using JDBC. The writes are around 1000 recs/sec.

The current activity we want to do as part of maintenance upgrades to Cassandra 6.0 from 3.2.4 so that in the new cluster we want to follow ideal Cassandra node configuration of having 1tb of data per node. What would be the ideal way of migration to 6.0 version of Cassandra? Without affecting the latency in the application. Also with ZDT(zero downtime) in Cassandra. 12 TB is a huge amount of data and compaction is a daunting task. We want to rectify this.

One solution we came up was using an offline and online model where old database 3.2.4 would still remain and new cluster Cassandra 6.0 would have smaller TTL. The only concern is that we want to avoid is latency in the application. Can Replication across DC with different versions of Cassandra help ?

Don't know the design decisions made during the development phase. But we want to rectify as part of maintenance. 
Correct me if our understanding is wrong.

Comment: You mean version of 6.0 of DataStax Enterprise?

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes 6.0 Datastax Enterprise

Comment: It’s too steep upgrade, and will require many intermediate steps. I recommend to go official route and contact DataStax for help...